# How to send Bluetooth Characters from Android App to a Bluetooth Device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, sample

I have searched all over the internet but couldn't find any sample bluetooth character transfer code.I am new to android ecosystem so please be descriptive.

Comment: There's a bluetooth chat sample.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I have tried it.But this different i guess

Comment: The principal is the same chars going over bluetooth device to device.  The hardest part is pairing the devices which is not part of the bluetooth chat pgm.